# postgis: union of faces of st_dump

Tags: postgis, sql, web

I am trying to make a web application that renders 3D buildings (LoD1). I have a PostGIS (2.2.1dev) database which contains the 2D geometry of the buildings and the height. I used st_extrude to make a 3D geometry out of it.

The problem is that I end up with a PolyhedralSurface, while I need a MultiPolygon. I used st_dump to split up my polyhedralSurface into its faces (floor, roof, walls). I end up with a table that has an id-column and a geometry-column.

For each building, I now have multiple rows in the table. The geometry column is of the form:

({1}, 01030000A8...).

The {i} part is the identifier for which face of my building it is, the second part is the actual geometry of this face.

How can I join the multiple rows for one building together and end up with a MultiPolygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out myself...

```
CREATE TABLE buildings_extrude AS
SELECT id, st_extrude(geom, 0, 0, height) as the_geom
FROM buildings;

CREATE TABLE buildings_dump AS
SELECT id, st_dump(the_geom) as the_geom
FROM buildings_extrude;

CREATE TABLE buildings_collect AS
SELECT id, st_collect((the_geom).geom) as the_geom
FROM buildings_dump
GROUP BY id;
```